# Hibernate data insertion slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate  in my project. I got a scenario where i save the object ,

```
remittanceTransactionDao.updateRemittanceTransaction(remittanceTransaction);
```

And then call the stored procedure which needs to access the data being  updated above.

```
 remittanceTransactionDao.deductAgentCommission(remittanceTransaction.getRemittanceNo(), "ADD");
```

But by that time, the first(update) statement is still not being executed in the db, so that the value the below method cant find. 
Is the Hibernate DB update slow or implementation poor? How can i optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate delays the updates to the database until it's really necessary. That allows improving performance by not doing unnecessary updates in case the transaction is rollbacked, and by batching statements.

To force it to write all the pending changes to the database, you need to call `Session.flush()`.

Comment: Solution was pretty simple. As you said, i called this.getsession.flush() and issue is settled. Thanks !